# How to optimize hibernate session usage in spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

We have a system with a high request volume and high depency on other external APIs. sometimes, when the external APIs are slow, this can cause the database connection pool reach its maximum connections.

We just increased this maximum number. But how can we keep the number of connections to the database low.
The thing is, 90% of time, the transaction/connection is really waiting for an http response. And there is no need to hold the connection.
Also, there is no need in this case to be acid compliant, it is mostly a read only database.

We could refactor to have two transactions, pre and post http. But it is not easy.

I was thinking is there a way for spring or hibernate to make this  optmization behind the scene?

Comment: Did you try to cache the data from external source? Another way would be to program your API with non blocking methods like Spring WebFlux.

Comment: We already cache a lot. And spring webflux would be an even greater refactor.

Answer (score 0):

You could commit and release the physical connection before you invoke the HTTP endpoint by using `org.hibernate.internal.Session#disconnect` to avoid this issue, but it's probably easier to just increase the number of connections and set a request timeout for the HTTP calls.